# Why root's password change doesn't require old password

Tags: security, root, passwd

Why can **`root`**'s password can be changed without entering the old password? Is there any benefit to this or is it just an implementation fault?   If we issue `passwd` from a normal user account it first asks for  " (Current) Unix Password: " but in the case of **`root`** it takes us directly to " Enter new Unix password: ". I don't understand the logic behind this.

Comment: One reason is that significantly often, you have a root shell but don't know the password, and need to change it. Since root has write access to `/etc/shadow` anyway, having the `passwd` tool require the old password wouldn't give any extra security.

Comment: Another reason is that root can directly edit `/etc/shadow` so there's no point in requiring root to enter the old password when running `passwd`, even when changing root's own password.  root can just generate a crypted or md5 password by some other means and edit it directly into `/etc/shadow`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Root owns and can write to both /etc/passwd and /etc/shadow anyway. Which does not mean the sysadmin SHOULD know her user's passwords. In fact, she should not know anything else than the root password.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of

- asking user, old password before changing

You may have left you keyboard/connection connected with you session open.
I might want to change your password. As a (little) security check, old password is asked, so system know rightfull user change password.

- root not being asked for other user password

You might have forger your password, a human being with admin right change it back to you. Root can edit /etc/passwd /etc/shadow, so to avoid messing up those files, root can change without check.

Answer (score -2):

Root may change any users password without entering the old value.

This is because the root user cannot know the old password for other users.

Not asking for the old password for root as well is orthogonal behavior.

Comment: Okay. i don't think the same case with its own password, it can be a security flaw? Isn't it?

Comment: No, it is just uniform behavior and root could do the change even without using the program `passwd`.

Comment: The question asks *why* -- this answer basically only repeats the same statement posed in the question, without any explanation of the reasoning involved.

Comment: Well, wid didn't you ask the other people who replied without explaining the background? The fact that root may change any password is documented in the man page. I added an obvious reason to my answer.